# Making an Apps Script function run on checkbox edits

Tags: google-apps-script, row, hide

As a fairly new user of Apps Script I'm trying to add a functionality to one of my sheets where I want to hide rows based on checkbox values. I'm using two tabs - one is the 'Settings' tab where I make the selection, the other is the 'Results' tab which has the actual data where I want the rows to get hidden. I've added four helper columns in my results tab that copy the checkmark values to that sheet, so the script only has to look at the values in this particular tab. I've stolen and slightly amended the script from this [URL](https://spreadsheet.dev/hide-rows-based-on-cell-value-google-sheets-apps-script) and now my script looks like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Custom Filter")
    .addItem("Filter rows", "filterRows")
    .addItem("Show all rows", "showAllRows")
    .addToUi();
}

function filterRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Results");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column A (1st column, hence the [0]) in the 'Results' tab is unchecked (false) then hide the row.
    if(data[i][0] === false) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function showAllRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Results");
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}
```

It's working as it should, the only change I want to make is that I'd rather not use the menu item to filter my rows, but instead I'd like the rows to get automatically hidden as I'm making changes to my selections in the checkboxes. I've tried looking online for an answer but haven't been able to find something that fits my needs. Hopefully someone here can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for an edit event when a user changes the value of a cell in a sheet (i.e. checks a box) using the [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

Answer (score 0):

Assume checkbox is in Sheet1!A1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == Sheet1 && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE"){
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    //run you function here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, however replacing my function onOpen part with yours it throws me an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2`

To clarify a bit further, this is how I currently have it setup. I have my settings sheet that looks like this: https://ibb.co/MNYJWVS.
As you can see in my first sheet I can fill out checkmarks in two different columns that then cause the checkmarks in my second sheet to also automatically get checked (these contain references to the cells in my first sheet): https://ibb.co/0qvdRZW

Comment: The checkboxes in column E on the first sheet get copied to column B of the second sheet. The top-right checkmarks of the Version table get put in column C of the second sheet and finally the checkmarks of the Device table get copied to column D.
Then column A has a formula that checks whether all of the columns B:D have a checkmark in them, if they do, then column A also gets a checkmark. If one or more checkmarks are missing in columns B:D, column A also does not get a checkmark.
Finally the App Script looks at column A to decide whether to hide the row or not (checkmark = don't hide).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are telling me because you are talking in terms of your application and I don't know anything about your application.  My expertise is in scripting so you need to ask me question in terms of scripting.

Comment: Alright, how about this: Replacing my onOpen function with your onEdit function throws me an error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:2'

Comment: Yes the event objects are entirely different